# How can I enable trusted X11 forwarding on Putty (with Xming) or otherwise get rid of one second delay when starting X11 aplication?

Tags: ssh, putty, xming

I've noticed one second delay before Midnight Commander or `mcedit` starts in Putty. It took me a while before I realized it is caused by X11 forwarding enabled. `mc -X` start immediately.

Unfortunately starting any X11 application has same delay. Maybe I'm nitpicking but it drives me crazy. Especially because some users mentioned cause and solution for this: `xming` does not support X11 security, so Linux must wait for network timeout. It is on second for me, but 30 seconds for others according to some discussions.

The solution is trusted X11 forwarding enabled by `-Y` commandline option for `ssh`. Unfortunately Putty doesn't have this option. Is there any other way to enable trusted forwarding on Putty ?

Answer (score 0):

The -Y or ForwardX11Trusted for ssh client disables access control for remote X clients. Putty does not propose it but **Xming** started with **-ac** disables access control as well.

This [xming tips](http://theunixtips.com/xming-client-4-rejected-from-ip/) page describes 2 ways to disable access control when Xming starts: using -ac parameter or modifying a file.

Is it better after Xming restart with access control disabled?

### ----

---

This first answer is left for reference.

**-C** might slow down communication on fast network (see ssh manual page), so I think it will not help in your situation.

**putty** 0.67 has both -X (turns on X11 forwarding in SSH) and -C (enable compression) see [3.8.3 Standard command-line options in the documentation.](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/puttydoc.txt)

Compression improves performance when used with ssh. 
The line below has been tested with a server far far away:

```
PUTTY.EXE -X -C -ssh 10.0.0.2
```

Let me know if it is better with both -X and -C in your environment?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try compression, but I did not mentioned I was working on localhost in virtual machine. Unfortunately -X in putty means X11 on, while in linux/cygwin ssh command -X means untrusted and -Y trusted. I've corrected it in my answer.

Comment: The ForwardX11Trusted for ssh client is disabling control for remote X client. Putty does not allow this but Xming shortcut can be modify to use **-ac**. It is also equivalent to **xhost +**.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Could you give it a try and tell me if it is better?

Comment: Thanks. I've tried both xming with commandline parameter and xlaunch with additional parameter for xming. There still was one second delay before mc or codeblocks started.

Comment: What if it is not due to the X11 Trusted? I mean it is worth to sniff packets with wireshark in order to figure out what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

PuTTY is safe enough with X11 forwarding. Please note that it may be necessary to install xauth on your Linux. After SSH login check if DISPLAY variable defined automatically. Its value should be localhost:... or similar. If not you should change to IPv4 only in your /etc/ssh/sshd_config and restart ssh service and try it again.