# ssh with xterm can't get screen resources

Tags: ssh, gui, xterm, putty

I am trying to launch a GUI of a program on my windows computer by ssh with putty.

I downloaded Xterm and have that running, and then in the putty options, I checked the box for X11 forwarding.

When I try to run my program, it comes up, but all greyed out. They terminal says:

```
failed to get the current screen resources
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 170 (Unknown), sequence: 170, resource id: 90, major code: 146 (Unknown), minor code: 20
Xlib:  extension "MIT-SHM" missing on display "localhost:24.0".
Xlib:  extension "MIT-SHM" missing on display "localhost:24.0".
Xlib:  extension "MIT-SHM" missing on display "localhost:24.0".
Xlib:  extension "MIT-SHM" missing on display "localhost:24.0".
Xlib:  extension "MIT-SHM" missing on display "localhost:24.0".
Xlib:  extension "MIT-SHM" missing on display "localhost:24.0".
Xlib:  extension "MIT-SHM" missing on display "localhost:24.0".
```

It keeps repeating this until I cntl+c out.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270160/how-can-i-enable-trusted-x11-forwarding-on-putty-with-xming-or-otherwise-get-r?rq=1)